# Xamarin: passing a downloaded image from a Page to another one

Tags: image, xamarin, stream

While I thought it would have been an easy task, I'm having hard times trying to pass and image, displayed in a Page to a new Page that has to display it full screen.
This is how it works:

```
    Stream imgStream = await _restService.GetArticleImgPath((int) barcode.Oarti);
    byte[] bytes = null;
    articleImg.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => imgStream};
```

This way it works. While searching around, I found out solutions using `byte[]`, but I'm having no luck.
Here's what I'm trying:

```
byte[] bytes = null;
articleImg.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => {
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            imgStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            imgStream.Dispose();
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        imgStream.Dispose();
        return imgStream;
        });
```

I still get `System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'`.
How can I simply pass the same image to a new Page, still using the new Page's constructor?

Comment: I would suggest writing to a file, and then passing the file path to the new page

Answer (score 1):

You could have a try with converting `Stream` to `byte[]`, and pass it to the next page.

For example , use the followings method:

```
public static class StreamExtensions
{
    public static byte[] ToByteArray(this Stream stream)
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
        for (int totalBytesCopied = 0; totalBytesCopied < stream.Length;)
            totalBytesCopied += stream.Read(buffer, totalBytesCopied, Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length) - totalBytesCopied);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Then can convert it (not caring about whether Stream will be closed):

```
//Stream imgStream = await _restService.GetArticleImgPath((int) barcode.Oarti);
// Here we can not dealing with a remote file, we need to store it in local file first 
Stream imgStream = getLocalfile();
byte[] bytes = StreamExtensions.ToByteArray(imgStream);
```

Comment: it says  "stream does not support seeking"

Comment: @exrezzo Okey, it's my mistake. Seeking is only supported for local files.You probably need to copy the file to your local file system. As Jason's said, we need to store steam to a local file, then we can deal with it.